# Will the following piece of code be considered as tail recursion?

Tags: tail-recursion

Is this below function is a tail recursion? And how to write it more efficiently and clearly.

Based on this question:
We build a table of n rows (1-indexed). We start by writing 0 in the 1st row. Now in every subsequent row, we look at the previous row and replace each occurrence of 0 with 01, and each occurrence of 1 with 10.

For example, for n = 3, the 1st row is 0, the 2nd row is 01, and the 3rd row is 0110.
Given two integer n and k, return the kth (1-indexed) symbol in the nth row of a table of n rows.

```
def kthGrammar(self, n: int, k: int) -> int:

    def getKvalue(k, predecessor):
        digit_place = k%2
        if predecessor == 0:
            return 1 if digit_place == 0 else 0
        elif predecessor == 1:
            return 0 if digit_place == 0 else 1
    
    
    def helper(n,k):
        if n==1:
            return 0
        prevK = int((k+1)/2)
        return getKvalue(k, helper(n-1,prevK))

    return helper(n,k)
```

Comment: [A recursive function is tail recursive when recursive call is the last thing executed by the function.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33923/what-is-tail-recursion). The recursive call to `helper` is not the last thing the function does. After `helper`, it calls `getKvalue`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your function currently tail recursive? No. The recursive call is then followed by a call to `getValue`.

Your function can be cleaned up dramatically, however. We will begin by replacing 0 and 1 with False and True.

```py
def kthGrammar(n: int, k: int) -> int:

    def getKvalue(k : int, predecessor : bool) -> bool:
        return (k % 2 == 0) != predecessor
    
    def helper(n : int, k : int) -> bool
        if n==1:
            return False
        prevK = (k+1) // 2
        return getKvalue(k, helper(n-1,prevK))

    return int(helper(n,k))
```

Let us further rewrite:

```py
def kthGrammar(n: int, k: int) -> int:
    
    def helper(n : int, k : int) -> bool
        if n==1:
            return False
        prevK = (k+1) // 2
        return (k % 2 == 0) != helper(n-1,prevK))

    return int(helper(n,k))
```

Now, we try something rather clever. We define `helper2(n : int, k : int, b : bool) = (b != helper(n, k))`. How can we implement `helper2` recursively?

Clearly, if `n = 1`, then `helper2(n, k, b) = (b != False) = b`. Otherwise, we have `helper2(n, k, b) = (b != helper(n, k)) = (b != ((k%2 == 0) != helper(n - 1, (k + 1) // 2)) = ((b != (k % 2 == 0)) != helper(n - 1, (k + 1) // 2)) = helper2(n - 1, (k + 1) // 2, b != (k % 2 == 0))`.

Note that I used the fact that for Booleans, `a != (b != c)` is identical to `(a != b) != c`.

Finally, note that `helper(n, k) = (False != helper(n, k) = helper2(n, k, False)`.

So we define

```py
def kthGrammar(n: int, k: int) -> int:
    
    def helper2(n : int, k : int, b : bool) -> bool
        if n==1:
            return b
        prevK = (k+1) // 2
        return helper2(n - 1, prevK, b != (k % 2 == 0))

    return int(helper2(n, k, False))
```

Now, we have a tail recursive function. Tail recursion is just another way to express iteration, so we can easily rewrite this to use a `while` loop as follows:

```py
def kthGrammar(n : int, k : int) -> int:
    b = False
    while n != 1:
        n, k, b = n - 1, (k + 1) // 2, b != (k % 2 == 0)
    return int(b)
```

Which can again be replaced by

```py
def kthGrammar(n : int, k : int) -> int:
    b = False
    for _n in range(n, 1, -1):
        k, b = (k + 1) // 2, b != (k % 2 == 0)
    return int(b)
```

Of course, there's no reason to start at `n` and count down to `1`. So the final form is

```py
def kthGrammar(n : int, k : int) -> int:
    b = False
    for _n in range(1, n):
        k, b = (k + 1) // 2, b != (k % 2 == 0)
    return int(b)
```

Note that we can actually perform one further optimisation. Once it is the case that `k = 1`, we see that the line

`k, b = (k + 1) // 2, b != (k % 2 == 0)`

is a no-op. So the final form is

```py
def kthGrammar(n : int, k : int) -> int:
    b = False
    for _n in range(1, n):
        if k == 1:
            break
        k, b = (k + 1) // 2, b != (k % 2 == 0)
    return int(b)
```

This will be much more efficient in the case that `k <= n` - the runtime is `O(min(n, log k))` as opposed to `O(n)`.